# Too much time to send mail with MS exchange SMTP server

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, exchange-server, office365

Hi all and thanks for your help

I use javamail to send mail throhght office365 SMTP server  ( smtp.office365.com) , but for some reason it keeps about 60-80 seconds to send mail.

```
stringaHost = "mail.smtp.host";
stringaUser = "mail.smtp.user";

Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider","com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl");
 Security.setProperty("ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider","com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl");

InitialContext initialContext = null;
initialContext = new InitialContext();

session = (Session)initialContext.lookup(nomeJndi);

session.getProperties().put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
session.getProperties().put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 465);
            session.getProperties().put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

MimeMessage MsgEmail = new MimeMessage( session );
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport t    =(com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtp");      

t.setStartTLS(true);
t.connect( smtp.office365.com,myUser,myPassword);
t.sendMessage( MsgEmail, MsgEmail.getAllRecipients());
t.close();
```

java mail spend more than 60 sec to evaluate instruction : t.connect(....) .

Any clue about what can happen and how can this time interval can be reduced ?

P.S. i tried to use t.connect() without parameters, by system technical says  that this instruction use SMTP transport protocol from operating system and don't use Office365 server transport protocol

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you [shouldn't need all those socket factory properties](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

If the delay is on the connect call, the possibilities are:

1. Your name service is slow in looking up the IP address for the server's host name.
2. The SSL negotiation is slow, perhaps due to certificate management on the client or server.
3. The server is slow authenticating you.

You can test #1 by seeing how long it takes InetAddress to look up the host name for your server.

You can test #2 by seeing how long it takes SSLSocket to make a connection to the server.

You can test #3 by either watching the JavaMail debug output in real time to see where the delay is, or getting time-stamped log messages from JavaMail.